# How to detect and make a mouse click on desktop with Dart

Tags: dart, events, mouseevent, dart-pub

Im looking for a Dart library that would allow me to detect and make a mouse click anywhere on the desktop. Something similar to robot in GOlang, or JNativeHook in Java.
Thanks in advance !
Scramjet_

Comment: Is this that u need? https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/flutter-handling-mouse-events-241108731537

Comment: No, this is related to flutter apps, my question is only about Dart (with or without flutter) and about mouse events anywhere on desktop, because the goal is to make an auto clicker in Dart. I could use win32 but i want a cross platform solution, so a library able to handle all OS.